# Parse img from RSS-feed using PHP SIMPLE HTML DOM Parser

Tags: html, image, parsing, dom

I am trying to parse this site (to get the img-link): http://statigr.am/feed/parishilton

This is my code:

```
include 'parse/simple_html_dom.php';

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://statigr.am/feed/parishilton/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
{
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
```

The script doesn't return anything! Why is that ? I want the `img` link.

Answer (score 0):

It's because all images are inside `CDATA` section and parser ignores it, so the solution is

```
$html = file_get_html('http://statigr.am/feed/parishilton/');
$html = str_replace("<![CDATA[","",$html); // clean-up
$html = str_replace("]]>","",$html); // clean-up
$html = str_get_html($html); // re-construct the dom object
// Loop
foreach($html->find('item description img') as $el)
{
    echo $el->src . "<br />";
}
```

Replace all `CDATA` from the returned content and then use `str_get_html` to create `DOM` object from that string and loop through the images. (Tested and works).

**Output :**

```
http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/cc25d8562c9611e3a8b922000a1f8ac2_8.jpg
http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/4d8e22da2c8911e3a6a022000ae81e78_8.jpg
http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/ce6aa38a2be711e391ae22000ae9112d_8.jpg
http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/d64ab4c42bc811e39cbd22000a1fafdb_8.jpg
......
......
```

Comment: Thanks!

And how do I do if I want the link, the description and the time when published, in the same array?

Output:

1. 
link: bla
description:xx
time: xx
2. link
description:xx
time: xx

Comment: `foreach($html->find('item') as $el)
 {
     echo $el->find('description img', 0)->src . "<br />";
     echo $el->find('link', 0)->innertext . "<br />";
     echo $el->find('pubDate', 0)->innertext . "<br />";
 }`

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart).